# I get this error message as "Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" when I execute my selenium scripts

Tags: java

I know what an OutOfMemoryError is, but what does GC overhead limit mean? How can I solve this?

Comment: please provide the permanent solution

Comment: You need to increase Java heap space in your machine. Read this q&a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemoryError is a subclass of java.lang.VirtualMachineError; it's thrown by the JVM when it encounters a problem related to utilizing resources. More specifically, the error occurs when the JVM spent too much time performing Garbage Collection and was only able to reclaim very little heap space.

[Refer this link for more details and how to find the problem](https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)